# regular expression for date validation in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following regular expression to validate the date in 'mm/dd/yyyy' format. It works for '12/11/2006'. But if I use '2/3/2011', it doesn't work. Could you please correct the following expression to accept '12/11/2006' or '2/3/2011' format? Thank you for help.

```
var date = /(0[1-9]|1[012])[- \/.](0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- \/.](19|20)\d\d/;
```

Comment: I'd suggest a simplified expression `/\d?\d[ \/.-]/\d?\d[ \/.-]\d{4}/` (or similar) - that is, any one- or two-digit number for day and month. I wouldn't bother restricting these within the regex just because you're going to have to separately test the values anyway to make sure that the date isn't too high for the given month and year combination (e.g., no Feb 30, and no Feb 29 unless a leap year).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var date = /(0?[1-9]|1[012])[- \/.](0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- \/.](19|20)\d\d/;
```

Just make the `0` optional: `0?`